# RSpec controller: redirect_to other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this issue with test my **CommentsController**:

> Failure/Error: redirect_to user_path(@comment.user), notice: 'Your
>   comment was successfully added!' ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}
>   missing required keys: [:id]

This is my method in my **controller**:

```
  def create 
    if params[:parent_id].to_i > 0
      parent = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment].delete(:parent_id))
      @comment = parent.children.build(comment_params)
    else
      @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    end
    @comment.author_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to user_path(@comment.user), notice: 'Your comment was successfully added!'
    else
      redirect_to user_path(@comment.user), notice: @comment.errors.full_messages.join
    end
  end
```

This is my **RSpec**:

```
  context "User logged in" do 
    before :each do 
      @user = create(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end 

    let(:comment) { create(:comment, user: @user, author_id: @user.id) }
    let(:comment_child) { create(:comment_child, user: @user, author_id: @user.id, parent_id: comment.id) }

    describe "POST #create" do 
      context "with valid attributes" do 
        it "saves the new comment object" do
          expect{ post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment), id: @user.id}.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
        end

        it "redirect to :show view " do 
          post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment), user: @user
          expect(response).to redirect_to user_path(comment.user)
        end
      end

      ...
    end
  end
```

My Comment **model**:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    acts_as_tree order: 'created_at DESC'

    VALID_REGEX = /\A^[\w \.\-@:),.!?"']*$\Z/
    validates :body, presence: true, length: { in: 2..240}, format: { with: VALID_REGEX }
end
```

How Can I add `user_id` to that request? When I change code in my controller `redirect_to user_path(@comment.user)` to `redirect_to user_path(current_user)` - test pass. May I `redirect_to` user in comments controller? Is any posibility to do it right? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the error is caused by the fact that the `@comment.user` is nil.

Lets start fixing it by cleaning up the spec:

```
context "User logged in" do 

  # declare lets first.
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:comment) { create(:comment, user: user, author: user) }
  # use do instead of braces when it does not fit on one line.
  let(:comment_child) do 
    # use `user: user` instead of `user_id: user.id`.
    # the latter defeats the whole purpose of the abstraction.
    create(:comment_child, user: user, author: user, parent: comment)
  end

  before { sign_in(user) }

  describe "POST #create" do 
    context "with valid attributes" do 
      it "saves the new comment object" do
        expect do 
          post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment) 
        end.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "redirects to the user" do 
        post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment)
        expect(response).to redirect_to user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You should generally avoid using instance vars and instead use `lets` in most cases. Using a mix just adds to the confusion since its hard to see what is lazy loaded or even instantiated where.

Then we can take care of the implementation:

```
def create
  @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @comment.user, notice: 'Your comment was successfully added!'
  else
    # ...
  end
end

private 
  def comment_params
    # note that we don't permit the user_id to be mass assigned
    params.require(:comment).permit(:foo, :bar, :parent_id)
  end
```

Basically you can cut a lot of the overcomplication:

- Raise an error if there is no authenticated user. With Devise you would do `before_action :authenticate_user!`.
- Get the user from the session - not the params. Your not going to want or need users to comment on the behalf of others.
- Wrap params in the `comments` key.
- Use `redirect_to @some_model_instance` and let rails do its polymorpic routing magic.
- Let ActiveRecord throw an error if the user tries to pass a bad `parent_id`.

Also does your Comment model really need both a `user` and `author` relationship? Surely one of them will suffice.

Comment: WOW! It's working! You are genius! Thanks a lot! Your answer is for me very important. I learned a lot! Thanks! :)

Comment: @comment.author_id is a variable to save actual user. How can I save in other way user who is author of comment? and where can I find magic for code refactor?

Comment: Added explaination on how the relation could be improved. There is no magic in refactoring - if that was the case than you could just bang out crap code and rely on the computer to fix it for you. Unfortunately thats not the case. There are code quality tools like Rubucop which do help a bit though.